# Way to get time string in mixed columns

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk

Way to get time string in these mixed columns:

```
new1   new11       1.1.1.1     application    id1223    831582      start   09:21:12 05/24/2013 --  --
new1   new11       1.1.1.1     application    ffd1234   1085500     start   --  --  09:21:04 05/24/2013
```

Expected view:

```
09:21:12 05/24/2013
09:21:04 05/24/2013
```

Comment: It is always good to show some effort. SO is not a coding team ready for your needs :)

Comment: And you mention a bunch of tools which could be used to do this. So have you tried any, yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really think you need to show some effort. Anyway (my fault) I couldn't help trying to do it with `grep`:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}'
```

The idea is get data with the following format `NN:NN:NN NN/NN/NNNN` where N is a number. `[0-9]{2}` stands for *2 times [0-9]*.

#### Test

```
$ grep -Eo '[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}' file
09:21:12 05/24/2013
09:21:04 05/24/2013
```

Even shorter (thanks [Jaypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789209/way-to-get-time-string-in-mixed-columns/16789427#comment24209438_16789427)):

```
grep -Eo '([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2} ([0-9]{2}/){2}[0-9]{4}'
```

Comment: We can simplify the regex to - `grep -Eo '([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2} ([0-9]{2}/){2}[0-9]{4}'`

Comment: Oh, good idea @Jaypal, it makes even more sense. I update my answer with your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/(\d+:\d+:\d+\s+\d+\/\d+\/\d+)/)' your_file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -r 's/.*start(.*)/\1/;s/-|  //g' file
```

or

```
awk '{gsub(/-/,"",$0);print $8,$9}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|.*(..:..:.. ../../....).*|\1|' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Print the columns in that range that aren't `"--"`:

```
perl -lane 'print "@{[grep { $_ ne q(--) } @F[7..$#F] ]}"' file
```